# Получается огромный JavaScript-файл в проекте. Как этого избежать?

Tags: webpack, symfony, encore, stimulus

При сборке JavaScript-файла в проекте Symfony размер итогового файла на порядки превышает размер составляющих его модулей. Из 4 килобайт выпекается пол-мегабайта.

Что-то можно с этим сделать в рамках Encore/Webpack/Stimulus?

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался. Я собирал файлы для dev-а:

```
npm run dev
```

Если собирать не для dev-a, а для релиза - получается вменяемый размер (тоже большой, но можно жить - около 50к)